# VBA SelectSingleNode xpath with multiple namespace

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xpath

I have simillar problem to others trying to search with xPath through XML with two namespaces but still looking on other topics it dosen't seem to work:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<IE515 xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns="http://www.mf.gov.pl/xsd/ECS/IE515_v1-0.xsd" NrWlasny=""
   EmailPodmiotu="">
   <Zgloszenie UCWywozu="" UCWyprowadzenia="PL441010"
      P1a="EX" P1b="A" LiczbaPozycji="" LiczbaOpakowan="" CRN=""
      KrajWysylki="" KrajPrzeznaczenia="" Kontenery="0" MasaBrutto="">
      <Nadawca TIN="" Nazwa="" UlicaNumer="" KodPocztowy="" Miejscowosc=""
         Kraj="" EORI=""/>
      <Odbiorca Nazwa="" UlicaNumer="" KodPocztowy=""
         Miejscowosc="" Kraj=""/>
      <ZglaszajacyPrzedstawiciel KodPocztowy=""
         Miejscowosc="" Kraj="" Nazwa="" TIN="" EORI="" UlicaNumer=""
         Wskaznik="00300" Przedstawicielstwo="1"/>
      <TransportWewnetrzny
         Rodzaj="5"/>
      <TransportNaGranicy Rodzaj="4" Znaki="SAMOLOT"
         Kraj="DE"/>
      <Lokalizacja UC=""/>
      <WarunkiDostawy Kod=""
         MiejsceKod="" Miejsce=""/>
      <Transakcja Waluta="" Wartosc=""
         Kurs=""/>
      <MiejsceData Miejsce="" NazwiskoImie="" Telefon=""
         Data=""/>
      <Towar Nr="1" OpisTowaru="TestName" KodTowarowy="30000" KodTaric="00"
         KrajPochodzenia="PL" ProceduraWnioskowana="10"
         ProceduraPoprzednia="00" MasaNetto="1.4">
         <IloscTowaru Jm="NAR"
            KwalifikatorJm="G" Ilosc="8"/>
         <Opakowanie Rodzaj="PA" Znaki=","
            LiczbaOpakowan="2"/>
         <KodDodatkowyUE Kod="4099"/>
         <DokumentWymagany
            Kod="9DK8" Nr="Oswiadczenie"/>
         <DokumentWymagany Kod="N380"
            Nr="OUT1"></DokumentWymagany>
         <DokumentWymagany Kod="Y903"
            Nr=","/>
         <DokumentWymagany Kod="Y935" Nr=","/>
         <DokumentWymagany
            Kod="Y922" Nr=","/>
         <InformacjaDodatkowa Kod="30400"/>
         <WartoscTowaru
            Waluta="PLN" WartoscStatystyczna="953">
            <Korekta Kod="1STW"
               Wartosc="-200"/>
         </WartoscTowaru>
      </Towar>
   </Zgloszenie>
</IE515>
```

in my code I'm trying to set NameSpace propoerty like this:

```
xmlNameSpaces = "xmlns='http://www.mf.gov.pl/xsd/ECS/IE515_v1-0.xsd' xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'"
doc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNameSpaces
```

and then try to search for the specific node, but it dosen't find the node:

```
Set oAttribute = doc.SelectSingleNode("/IE515/Zgloszenie/Towar[1]/@OpisTowaru")`
```

Can you explain how the namespace propperty should look like to make it work? I can do this if I have onl

Comment: "*I can do this if I have onl...*", would you mind completing your sentence?

Comment: sorry something was cut out, it works when I remove te second namesamece: `xmlns="http://www.mf.gov.pl/xsd/ECS/IE515_v1-0.xsd` but when i have two, it dosen't :/

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign prefix to the namespace when setting `SelectionNamespaces` property, so that you can use the prefix in your xpath later on :

```
xmlNameSpaces = "xmlns:d='http://www.mf.gov.pl/xsd/ECS/IE515_v1-0.xsd'"
doc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNameSpaces

Set oAttribute = doc.SelectSingleNode("/d:IE515/d:Zgloszenie/d:Towar[1]/@OpisTowaru")
```

Notice prefix `d:` in above xpath corresponds to the `xmlns:d` in `xmlNameSpaces`.

Comment: This dosen't work :/  it only works when I modify xml (only for testing) by adding prefix to the sceond namespace like for example S, then it works fine   `<IE515 xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:s="http://www.mf.gov.pl/xsd/ECS/IE515_v1-0.xsd" NrWlasny=""
   EmailPodmiotu=""> ` but i can't change the xml..

Comment: Hi @user3313162 please, look closely at the answer again. No need to change your XML, you only need to add prefix in `xmlNameSpaces` variable, and to the xpath in `SelectSingleNode()` parameter.

Comment: If eventually you still unable get it to work, please post your updated code showing how you exactly tried to implement the suggested solution.